# How to setup Javacc in windows 10

Tags: java, parsing, lexer, javacc

How do I install javacc in Windows 10?

I visited https://javacc.github.io/javacc/, but there's no clear instruction to set it up on Windows.

Comment: What specific steps have you tried from the ones in your link? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I already added path of the folder javacc, and I don't know what should I do next.

Comment: Did you download the source from github? Or are you using the pre-built binary they provide? I'm not clear where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I downloaded it from https://javacc.github.io/javacc/#getting-started, javacc-7.0.5.zip. I already added the path of the folder, and I don't know what I should do next..

Comment: I don't understand this part, "Then place the binary javacc-7.0.5.jar in a new target/ folder, and rename to javacc.jar.

Once you have completed installation add the scripts/ directory in the JavaCC installation to your PATH. The JavaCC, JJTree, and JJDoc invocation scripts/executables reside in this directory.

On UNIX based systems, the scripts may not be executable immediately. This can be solved by using the command from the javacc-7.0.5/ directory:

chmod +x scripts/javacc "

Comment: I tried another version of javacc and it worked. I tried entering javacc in cmd and it shows its version

Comment: Excellent! Feel free to answer your own question with the detailed steps you figured out. That will help others who may hit the same issue in the future. You can even accept your own answer, if it's the most helpful one.

Answer (score 10):

***Update**: I have made some changes to the steps, and provided some notes about those changes at the end.*

---

I know the OP switched to using version 6, but here are the instructions for version 7:

(Version 7.0.5, to be precise.)

### Set-Up:

1. Go to the "Getting Started" page [here](https://javacc.github.io/javacc/#getting-started).
2. Download the zip file from the "Source(zip)" link.
3. Unzip that into a directory of your choosing. I chose a new empty directory  `E:\javacc`. That ended up giving me everything in `E:\javacc\javacc-7.0.5`.
4. Create a new `target` directory. For me, that was `E:\javacc\javacc-7.0.5\target`.
5. *NO NEED TO DO THIS*: Download the jar file from the "Getting Started" page, using the "Binaries" link. That gives you a file `javacc-7.0.5.jar`.
6. Locate the `javacc.jar` file in the `bootstrap` directory. Copy that file to the new `target` directory.
7. Add the `scripts` directory (for me: `E:\javacc\javacc-7.0.5\scripts`) to your `PATH` environment variable. I assume that does not need specific instructions.

### Verify:

To test the installation:

1. Open a **new** command prompt (to pick up the PATH changes), and navigate to the javacc installation directory (for me: `E:\javacc\javacc-7.0.5`).
2. Execute the following command:

```
javacc
```

This should give you a screenful of output, starting with:

```
E:\javacc\javacc-7.0.5>java -cp target/javacc.jar javacc
Java Compiler Compiler Version 7.0.5 (Parser Generator)

Usage:
    javacc option-settings inputfile
```

Similarly, you should be able to run the `jjdoc` and `jjtree` commands.

---

**Update**

The above steps were, indeed, unnecessarily complicated - as noted in comments. I have made some simplifications (used with v7.0.10). Those are shown above.

The objective when using the JavaCC zip file is to be able to execute each JavaCC command (e.g. `javacc`) on the command line directly.

You can run JavaCC commands using only the JAR file, as follows:

```
java -cp javacc.jar javacc
```

Using this approach, you will not have access to `javacc` (or the other commands) directly on the command line: they will not be on your `PATH`.

Comment: This method is extremely complicated.  Why not put the appropriate .jar file in the appropriate directory in the distribution?

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell I wonder why? anyone know the reason??

Comment: @Mahi I didn't have an answer when I asked the question and I still don't have an answer. If this is still a problem, please file an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the same steps in the Installation part of the guide.

https://javacc.github.io/javacc/#getting-started

After you have unzipped the downloaded file into a new directory, you need to add the path of the folder to your PATH variable in Windows. To do that, follow this guide:

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: What should I do after I added the path? I don't understand what should I do next after that

Comment: I tried other version of javacc which is 6.0.1 and it worked. I entered javacc in cmd and it shows its version

Comment: If it showed the version, it should be all set to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse as your IDE, you can install JavaCC from the marketplace. Just go to `help`, then click on `Eclipse Marketplace` and when it loads just type "JavaCC" on the search bar and install the plugin. I'm not sure if it's the latest version, but it works well and it's simpler to install.